# Sort records using Pageable with given order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring boot project and have the get API to display the records from the database with certain filters along with pagination to achieve that I am using the JPA with JPA Specifications. API is working fine with given filter options and paginations params. Now I want to sort them based on the field with a decs|asc order dynamically.

**API**

```
@GetMapping("/opportunities")
  public ResponseEntity<List<Opportunities>> findAll(Pageable pageable,
      @RequestParam(required = false) String ..,
      @RequestParam(required = false) String ..,
      @RequestParam(required = false) String ..,
      @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean ..,
      @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "true") boolean ..) {
    opportunityService.findAll(..., pageable);
  }
```

**Method**

```
  @Override
  public Page<Opportunity> findAll(String .., String .., String ..,
      Boolean .., boolean .., Pageable pageable) {

    OpportunityFilters opportunityFilters = new OpportunityFilters();
    ... // set filters
    OpportunitySpecification opportunitySpecification =
        new OpportunitySpecification(opportunityFilters);
    Page<Opportunity> page = opportunityRepository.findAll(opportunitySpecification,
        pageable);
    ...
}
```

**OpportunityRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface OpportunityRepository extends JpaRepository<Opportunity, String>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Opportunity> {
}
```

When I hit the API with the sort param and set the field name it sort the records properly but I want to set the sort order dynamically in the request. How can I set the sort order here?

http://localhost:8080/api/opportunities?page=0&size=10&sort=name

Comment: it should be something like `&sort=field,(ASC|DESC)`. have you tried this: `&sort=name,DESC` for descending order or `&sort=name,ASC` for ascending order ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it adding the sort direction (`,asc`, or `,desc`) in the `sort` parameter of the API request. For example, if you want to sort by the name field in descending order, you can make the following request:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/opportunities?page=0&size=10&sort=name,desc
```

Spring Boot will automatically handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your url like this

```
http://localhost:8080/api/opportunities?page=0&size=10&sortField=name&order=asc
```

Then through @RequestParam you can take order value from url then send that order value to findAll method and change your code like this

```
     @Override
      public Page<Opportunity> findAll(String .., String .., String ..,
          Boolean .., boolean .., Pageable pageable) {
    
        OpportunityFilters opportunityFilters = new OpportunityFilters();
        ... // set filters
        OpportunitySpecification opportunitySpecification =
            new OpportunitySpecification(opportunityFilters);
 Sort sort = order.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? 
 Sort.by(sortField).ascending(): Sort.by(sortField).descending();
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, sort);
        Page<Opportunity> page = opportunityRepository.findAll(opportunitySpecification,
            pageable);
        ...
    }
```

I don't know where you are creating pageable object but while creating pagable object you have to use sort object to perform sorting with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

check it once

```java
Pageable pageDesc = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize,Sort.by("fieldYouRequired").descending());
Pageable pageAsc = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, Sort.by("fieldYouRequired").ascending());
Page<Opportunity> page =opportunityRepository.findAll(opportunitySpecification,pageDesc/pageAsc);
```